# OpenGL render multiple objects using single VBO and updata object's matrices using another VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

So, I need the way to render multiple objects(not instances) using one draw call. Actually I know how to do this, just to place data into single vbo/ibo and render, using glDrawElements.

The question is: what is efficient way to update uniform data without setting it up for every single object, using glUniform...?

How can I setup one buffer containing all uniform data of dozens of objects, include MVP matrices, bind it and perform render using single draw call? 
I tried to use UBOs, but it's not what I need at all.

For rendering instances we just place uniform data, including matrices, at another VBO and set up attribute divisor using glVertexAttribDivisor, but it only works for instances.

Is there a way to do that I want in OpenGL? If not, what can I do to overcome overheads of setting uniform data for dozens of objects?

For example like this:

```
{
    // setting up VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(vbo);
    glBufferData(..., data_size);

    // setup buffer
    for(int i = 0; i < objects_num; i++)
        glBufferSubData(...offset, size, &(objects[i]));

    // the same for IBO
    .........
    // when setup some buffer, that will store all uniforms, for every object
    .........
    glDrawElements(...);
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Why are UBOs not what you need? It sounds like it could solve your problem. On another note, are you sure that this is your program's bottleneck? Sounds a little like premature optimization to me...

Comment: It didnt solve problem because, where will really a lot of objects, not 10 or 100, but more. And UBO are used to just setup shader uniform blocks, i.e. there is need to update it for every single object.(even if storing all uniform data in singl UBO) So, Reto Koradi, gave a good answer, I think it explains everything that I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're ok with requiring OpenGL 4.3 or higher, I believe you can render this with a single draw call using `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect()`. This allows you to essentially make multiple draw calls with a single API call. Each sub-call is defined by values in a struct of the form:

```
typedef  struct {
    GLuint  count;
    GLuint  instanceCount;
    GLuint  firstIndex;
    GLuint  baseVertex;
    GLuint  baseInstance;
} DrawElementsIndirectCommand;
```

Since you do not want to draw multiple instances of the same vertices, you use 1 for the `instanceCount` in each draw call. The key idea is that you can still use instancing by specifying a different `baseInstance` value for each one. So each object will have a different `gl_InstanceID` value, and you can use instanced attributes for the values (matrices, etc) that you want to vary per object.

So if you currently have a rendering loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < objectCount; ++k) {
    // set uniforms for object k.
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, object[k].indexCount,
                   GL_UNSIGNED_INT, object[k].indexOffset * sizeof(GLuint));
}
```

you would instead fill an array of the struct defined above with the arguments:

```
DrawElementsIndirectCommand cmds[objectCount];
for (int k = 0; k < objectCount; ++k) {
    cmds[k].count = object[k].indexCount;
    cmds[k].instanceCount = 1;
    cmds[k].firstIndex = object[k].indexOffset;
    cmds[k].baseVertex = 0;
    cmds[k].baseInstance = k;
}

// Rest of setup.

glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, objectCount, 0);
```

I didn't provide code for the full setup above. The key steps include:

- Drop the `cmds` array into a buffer, and bind it as `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER`.
- Store the per-object values in a VBO. Set up the corresponding vertex attributes, which includes specifying them as instanced with `glVertexAttribDivisor(1)`.
- Set up the per-vertex attributes as usual.
- Set up the index buffer as usual.

For this to work, the indices for all the objects will have to be in the same index buffer, and the values for each attribute will have to be in the same VBO across all objects.

Comment: Yes, yes, thank you, it what I wanted and seems it works fine for me. Great answer!